# Asp.Net Update Pannel from Another update panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have 1 page, 2 controls and 2 update panels. Control (A) has and update panel inside it. Control (B) doesn't. Both Control A and Control B are on the same Page and I have wrapped an update panel around Control (B) in the page.

Now my question is: Given an event that causes a postback on Control(A)(the control with the update panel inside the control) is is possible to update the UI on Control(B)(That is wrapped in an update panel on the Page) during a postback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both update panels not marked with UpdateMode="Conditional", if its set to always, they should refresh itself by default.  You probably only need the one to act this way.

HTH.